# PHP function for form not working

Tags: php, function

Why is this php function not working? It does work when not using $element.
With $element it always returns test.

```
function setVar($element)
 {
    if(isset($_POST['$element'])){
    $varname = $_POST['$element']; 
    } 
    else {
    $varname = 'test';
    }
    return $varname;
 }

 $var = setVar('element_6');
```

Comment: shorter version `return isset($_POST[$element])?$_POST[$element]:'test';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
... $_POST[$element] ...
```

without the quotes? Single-quoted content never gets replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$_POST['$element']` in your code to `$_POST[$element]` and it should work fine.. $_POST['$element']) refers to nothing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change $_POST['$element'] to $_POST[$element]. Anything between single quotes is treated literally.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `$_POST['$element']`. Note that the single quotes around `$element` here turn it into a static string.

Solution: Remove the quote marks, and it will parse the `$element` properly.